# Difference between using aliases in outer query of subquery or not using them

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have code with or without using aliases in outer query. Both work well and provide similar result.

Not using aliases in outer query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (msg_id, msg_checksum) *
FROM 

(
SELECT id, jsonb_var,  
       jsonb_var ->> 'id' as msg_id,
       jsonb_var ->> 'checksum' as msg_checksum
FROM testing_json_as_table
) AS subquery_table_with_msg_id_and_msg_checksum

ORDER BY msg_id, msg_checksum;
```

Using aliases in outer query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (subquery_table_with_msg_id_and_msg_checksum.msg_id, subquery_table_with_msg_id_and_msg_checksum.msg_checksum) *
FROM 

(
SELECT id, jsonb_var,  
       jsonb_var ->> 'id' as msg_id,
       jsonb_var ->> 'checksum' as msg_checksum
FROM testing_json_as_table
) AS subquery_table_with_msg_id_and_msg_checksum

ORDER BY subquery_table_with_msg_id_and_msg_checksum.msg_id, subquery_table_with_msg_id_and_msg_checksum.msg_checksum;
```

My question is:

1. Why both code give similar result?
2. When I should use aliases in outer query and when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I recommend always qualifying column names (i.e. using the aliases).  Parallel with that, I recommend simple aliases, abbreviations.  So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (tjt.msg_id, tjt.msg_checksum) *
FROM (SELECT id, jsonb_var,  
             jsonb_var ->> 'id' as msg_id,
             jsonb_var ->> 'checksum' as msg_checksum
      FROM testing_json_as_table
     ) tjt
ORDER BY tjt.msg_id, tjt.msg_checksum;
```

Here `tjt` abbreviates `testing_json_as_table`.

That said, if you are only referencing one table one time in your query (as in this example), then you can relax that "always qualify all columns" rule.

Comment: So if in inner query there is one table than in outer query without or with aliases the result be the same? But if there are 2 or mire tables with same column names in inner query than using aliases is mandatory? Also can you please tell me more about  ""always qualify all columns" rule" ?

Comment: The *always qualify all columns* rule means literally that:, every table in every SQL statement is given an alias and every reference to any column is always prefixed with that alias.  Self joins added a suffix to disambiguate the individual tables.  Had an app few years ago where we took this a step further. Every table was assigned a unique alias when created and that alias was used in every reference,including PK, FK, and UK names. Not using the alias automatically failed code review. Seemed a little strange at first but but once getting used to it it seemed the natural way.